# Implementing Spotify Web API into my Android App

Tags: android-studio, spotify, webapi

I am trying to access music information such as playlists, songs, artists, etc. from Spotify's API but do not know how to go about it. I was reading into Spotify's Android SDK but it requires the Spotify app to be downloaded on the device.

Would it be possible to access Spotify's Web API from my Android App? If so, what would I need to import/add to my project and what language will I need to know.

I'm just looking for some direction so any information would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Spotify Web API specifically, you can authorize your custom app following this [guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/).

Not knowing about your Android knowledge, I suggest being familiar with the basic principles that can be learned [here](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course) before starting the development of your app.